# вывод текста в консоль с помощью get

Tags: python, tkinter

В программе должна вывестись информация из entrypassword в консоль, но она почему то не выводится.
Прошу вашей помощи.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry(f"700x300+500+300")
window.title("user")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def entrypassword2():
    entry = entrypassword.get()
    if entrypassword:
        print(entry)
entrypassword = tk.Entry(window)
textpassword = tk.Label(window, text="Введите пароль: ", font="Arial 12")
entryname = tk.Entry(window)
textname = tk.Label(window,text="Введите имя: ", font = "Arial 12")
entrypassword2 = tk.Entry(window)
infbutton = tk.Button(window, text="inf", command=entrypassword2) 

infbutton.grid(column=3, row=5)
entrypassword2.place(x=100, y=50)
entrypassword.place(x=132, y=28)
entryname.place(x=108, y=4)
textpassword.place(x=1, y=25)
textname.place(x=1, y=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сначала создали функцию `entrypassword2` а затем переменную с таким-же именем `entrypassword2 = tk.Entry(window)` и функции больше нет :(